# Convert json date format with php to something like mm/dd/yy

Tags: php, json

How do I go about converting date to a readable format like `mm/dd/yy`? The code below is giving me this: /Date(1335412800000)/

```
<?php echo '<td>'.$r['effdate'].'</td>'; ?> //displaying this now: /Date(1335412800000)/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
    $effdate = date('m/j/Y', preg_replace('/[^\d]/','', $r['effdate'])/1000);    
    echo '<td>'.$effdate.'</td>';
?>
```

I am removing all the non digits.

`preg_replace('/[^\d]/','', $r['effdate'])`

Dividing it by 1000 as epoch times in JavaScript is x 1000.

`/1000`

Then I return the formatted date.

`date('m/j/Y', ...`